# Terraform Error: "replication_group_id": conflicts with engine_version. ( redis )

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to create an `aws_elasticache_replication_group` using Redis

```
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "encryption-at-rest" {
  count           = 1
  cluster_id      = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-encryption-at-rest"
  engine          = "redis"
  engine_version  = var.engine_version
  node_type       = var.node_type
  num_cache_nodes = 1
  port            = var.redis_port
  #az_mode            = var.az_mode
  replication_group_id = aws_elasticache_replication_group.elasticache_replication_group.id
  security_group_ids   = [aws_security_group.redis_security_group.id]
  subnet_group_name    = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.default.name
  apply_immediately    = true
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-redis"
  }

}

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elasticache_replication_group" {

  automatic_failover_enabled    = false               //var.sharding_automatic_failover_enabled
  availability_zones            = ["ap-southeast-1a"] //data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.availability_zones
  replication_group_id          = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-encryption-at-rest"
  replication_group_description = "${var.namespace} ${var.environment} replication group"
  security_group_ids            = [aws_security_group.redis_security_group.id]
  subnet_group_name             = aws_elasticache_subnet_group.default.name
  node_type                     = var.node_type
  number_cache_clusters         = 1 //2
  parameter_group_name          = aws_elasticache_parameter_group.param_group.name
  port                          = var.redis_port
  at_rest_encryption_enabled    = true
  kms_key_id                    = data.aws_kms_alias.kms_redis.target_key_arn
  apply_immediately             = true
}

resource "aws_elasticache_parameter_group" "param_group" {
  name   = "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-params"
  family = "redis5.0"
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
aws_security_group_rule.redis_ingress[0]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-3474516270]
aws_security_group_rule.redis_ingress[1]: Refreshing state... [id=sgrule-2582511137]
aws_elasticache_replication_group.elasticache_replication_group: Refreshing state... [id=cbpl-uat-encryption-at-rest]

Error: "replication_group_id": conflicts with engine_version

  on redis.tf line 1, in resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "encryption-at-rest":
   1: resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "encryption-at-rest" {


Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Comment: what is the value of `var.engine_version`

Comment: Your question title says you are getting an error about the `replication_group_id` conflicting with `engine_version` and the included error matches this. However you introduce the error by saying that "the replication group expects a redis4.0 parameter group". Which error exactly is it that you have? I've answered according to the question title and error output but you should clarify/fix this.

Answer (score 2):

The [`aws_elasticache_cluster` resource docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticache_cluster.html) say this:

> - `replication_group_id` - (Optional) The ID of the replication group to
>   which this cluster should belong. If this parameter is specified, the
>   cluster is added to the specified replication group as a read replica;
>   otherwise, the cluster is a standalone primary that is not part of any
>   replication group.
> - `engine` – (Required unless `replication_group_id` is provided) Name
>   of the cache engine to be used for this cache cluster. Valid values
>   for this parameter are `memcached` or `redis`

If you're going to join it to a replication group then the engine must match the replication group's engine type and so it shouldn't be set on the `aws_elasticache_cluster`.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS provider overloads the `aws_elasticache_cluster` structure to handle multiple dissimilar configurations. The internal logic contains a set of ['ConflictsWith' validations](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/ec68e36cee6622a4d55346fa693dc0092d689358/internal/service/elasticache/cluster.go#L228) which are based on the premise that certain arguments simply cannot be specified together because they represent different modes of elasticache clusters (or nodes).

If you are specifying a `replication_group_id` then the value of `engine_version` will be managed by the corresponding aws_elasticache_replication_group.

Therefore, **the solution** is simply to remove the `engine_version` argument from your [`aws_elasticache_cluster`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster) resource specification. If you so choose (or in cases where it is required), you can also add that argument to the [`aws_elasticache_replication_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_replication_group).

Example: [Redis Cluster Mode Disabled Read Replica Instance](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_cluster#redis-cluster-mode-disabled-read-replica-instance)

```hcl
// These inherit their settings from the replication group.
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "replica" {
  cluster_id           = "cluster-example"
  replication_group_id = aws_elasticache_replication_group.example.id
}
```

*In this mode, the `aws_elasticache_cluster` structure requires very few arguments.*

Comment: P.S. I think it's possible for this [`ConflictsWith`](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/ec68e36cee6622a4d55346fa693dc0092d689358/internal/service/elasticache/cluster.go#L228) definition to be overeager. I've just encountered an issue (bug) where, because it forbids use of `snapshot_retention_limit`, there is (apparently) no way to specify that the node is used for backups.

Comment: It turns out that you normally aren't meant to use `aws_elasticache_cluster` with 'Cluster Mode Disabled'. The replication group will create and manage those automatically when you specify [`num_cache_clusters`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_replication_group#redis-cluster-mode-disabled). Furthermore, trying to manage them yourself (with `aws_elasticache_cluster`) presents some [challenges](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/5590).