# "global_replication_group_id": conflicts with parameter_group_name in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here, we use `aws_elasticache_global_replication_group` in `terraform` to add the multi-region elasticache redis cluster in AWS. Here is the code we are trying and we get `"global_replication_group_id": conflicts with parameter_group_name` error after applying the terraform plan.

```
resource "aws_elasticache_global_replication_group" "global-redis" {
  

  global_replication_group_id_suffix = "global-redis"
  primary_replication_group_id       = aws_elasticache_replication_group.primary.id
}

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "primary" {    
  replication_group_id          = "redis-primary"
  replication_group_description = "primary replication group"

  engine         = "redis"
  engine_version = "5.0.6"
  node_type      = "cache.m5.large"

  snapshot_retention_limit   = var.snapshot_retention
  parameter_group_name       = var.parameter_group_name
  availability_zones         = var.availability-zones-primary

  number_cache_clusters = 1
}

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "secondary" {
  replication_group_id          = "redis-secondary"
  replication_group_description = "secondary replication group"
  global_replication_group_id   = aws_elasticache_global_replication_group.global-redis.global_replication_group_id

  snapshot_retention_limit   = var.snapshot_retention
  parameter_group_name       = var.parameter_group_name
  availability_zones         = var.availability-zones-secondary

  number_cache_clusters = 1
  provider = aws.other_region
}
```

We couldn't find any documentation regarding this error and looking for answers if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: What is your var.parameter_group_name actually set to?
Are you creating the parameter group via terraform resource & if so, does it have the parameter; cluster-enabled set to true?
Lastly, if you're able, have you tried not setting the parameter_group_name (since it's optional & will use a default one otherwise)?

Comment: What is `var.parameter_group_name`?

Comment: var.parameter_group_name = default.redis6.x

Comment: Closely related cause: [Terraform Error: "replication_group_id": conflicts with engine_version. ( redis )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544763/terraform-error-replication-group-id-conflicts-with-engine-version-redis)